# Can a new process with non-zero resource requirements be added while Banker's Algorithm is running without introducing deadlock?

Tags: process, operating-system, ipc, interprocess

I know that [banker's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker%27s_algorithm) requires a maximum resource needs for every process to ensure that system does not go into deadlock. But in real systems neither the resources available nor the demands of processes for resources are consistent over time.

So what happens when a new process is added while banker's algorithm is running? Could it result in deadlock?